# How to integrate "Google Firebase Analytics" in ionic apps?

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-analytics

In the official [Firebase Integration Guide (Android)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and [Firebase Integration Guide (iOS)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup), they have provided individual integration guidelines.

Could you please tell me an ionic way I can integrate `Firebase Analytics` into ionic apps?

I need to do this as AdMob made the `Firebase Analytics` as its recommendation analytics solution for mobile apps.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have the same question, too. :)

Comment: I think new Google firebase does not support this feature currently, maybe you could use `$cordovaGoogleAnalytics` as an alternative?

Comment: How about with Ionic 2?

Comment: @Sagar .. could you find an answer to this question ?

Comment: @Sushil Not yet!

Comment: What is your ionic version ?

Answer (score 3):

Worth keeping any eye on this thread:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/MKfIzAtNNuA

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime, an Ionic Native plugin on top of the Cordova plugin cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics has been released: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-analytics/

It's still in beta, but I had no problems with it so far (except for a conflict with phonegap-plugin-push).
The integration is very straight forward:

```
import { FirebaseAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/firebase-analytics';

constructor(private firebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics) { ... }
```

To track an event just call logEvent:

```
this.firebaseAnalytics.logEvent('page_view', {page: "dashboard"})
  .then((res: any) => console.log(res))
  .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like someone created a repository for [Firebase in Cordova](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase), you should be able to use that. It says that it will give you at least push notifications, analytics, event tracking, crash reporting.